# SQL Server - how to manually increment a PK in multiple-row INSERT transaction

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server.  I have a table that has a PK int column.  This column does not have auto-increment enabled, and I am not allowed to change the schema.  I need to insert lots of rows (perhaps thousands) into this table manually.  None of the data inserted will come from any existing table.  However, I need to ensure that the PK column gets incremented by +1 for each new row.  My current script is like the following:

```
BEGIN TRAN
    INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.table1
    (PK_col, col1)
    VALUES
    (10, 'a')
    ,(11, 'something')
    ,(12, 'more text')
    ;
```

where I already know via a pre-query (`SELECT MAX(PK_col) + 1`) that PK_col is currently at 9.

My problem is ensuring that the PK column gets incremented by +1 for each new row.  Because there could be thousands of rows to insert, I want to reduce the possibility of skipping values or a PK constraint violation being thrown.  I know that I can achieve this outside of the DB (via Excel), as long as I validate the PK values prior to running the SQL script.  However, I would like to create a solution that handles the auto-increment within the TRAN statement itself.  Is this possible (without running into a race condition)?  If so, how?

Comment: Yes it is possible. By far the easiest solution is to use an identity. It will do all those things for you with absolutely zero effort on your part.

Comment: How do I use an identity when I am not allowed to change the table schema?

Comment: You could use a sequence depending on which version of sql server you are using. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx Is this something you have to do frequently? Sounds like changing the table to have an identity would be something I would push for but I don't know all the details of course.

Comment: No, I do not update the table frequently.  Maybe once a month.  And, it's not actually me who does the update.  Other colleagues of mine do the update, and I don't trust their SQL skills or data validation effort.  (That's an entirely different problem.)  I can push for an identity on the table all I want, but my recommendations are always ignored.

Comment: I feel your pain on recommendations being ignored. I usually suggest the opposite of what I really want because that is what almost always happens anyway. Well either using a sequence or the simpler approach suggested by Gordon is what I would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.table1(PK_col, col1)
    SELECT COALESCE(l.max_pk_col, 0) + row_number() over (order by (select null)) as PK_col,
           col1
    FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('something'), ('more text')) v(col1) CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(pk_col) as max_pk_col FROM DB1.dbo.table1) l;
```

You need to be careful with this arrangement.  Locking the entire table for the duration of the `INSERT` is probably a good idea -- if anything else could be updating the table.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create a new temporary table with an identity column and a data column, do your insert and then insert the contents of this table back into your desired original table. Then clean it up

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @initialIndex INT

SELECT @initialIndex = MAX(PK_col) + 1)
FROM DB1.dbo.table1

CREATE TABLE #tempData(
  PK_col INT IDENTITY(@initialIndex, 1),
  col1 VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #tempData (col1)
VALUES
('a')
,('something')
,('more text')

INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.table1
SELECT PK_col, col1
FROM #tempData

DROP TABLE #tempData
```